# Input from users for batch script

Tags: batch-file, ssid

I am new to this so if I have put this in the wrong area or done something wrong, please let me know what I need to do to fix it.

During lockdown, I started messing about with Batch to create a menu system to automatically connect my NAS drives.  Got to tinkering and added a whole host of other things to the menu system.  My latest wee project is for a batch file to show what wifi SSID you are connected to and show the user the SSID password in plain text.

My question is regarding grabbing user input from a batch script.  I currently have the following :

```
:WIFI
CLS
@echo off
@echo  =======================================================================================================
@echo.
@echo Current SSID in range
netsh wlan show networks | findstr SSID
echo.
@echo  Please type in your current connected WiFi name 
set /p  SSID="SSID: "
echo your SSID is: %SSID%
@echo.
@echo  =======================================================================================================
@echo.
PAUSE
CLS
goto SSID

:SSID
@echo  =======================================================================================================
@echo.
@echo  Current connected WiFi and connection password is :
@echo.
NETSH WLAN SHOW PROFILE %SSID% KEY=CLEAR | findstr Name
NETSH WLAN SHOW PROFILE %SSID% KEY=CLEAR | findstr Key 
@echo.
@echo  =======================================================================================================
@echo.
PAUSE
CLS
GOTO RETURN
```

When I run the script, the first part comes back as the following
[image: Output snap]

The script works absolutely fine, however, I am looking for a way to be able to have the user just hit the relevant number by the SSID, rather than have to type things out.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Failing that, does anyone have any ideas on how to get the batch to automatically show the SSID that is connected to and then run the second part of the script?

I ended up going with the following :

That works an absolute treat, thank you. I have changed it a little bit to the following:

```
:WIFI
CLS
setlocal 
set "current=no network"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('netsh wlan show all ^| find " SSID  "') do set "current=%%a"
@echo.
@echo  =======================================================================================================
@echo.
echo     Your SSID is           : %current%
NETSH WLAN SHOW PROFILE %current% KEY=CLEAR | findstr Key 
@echo.
@echo  =======================================================================================================
@echo.
PAUSE
CLS
```

Comment: Please don't include the answer into the question. It invalidates the question and attracts downvotes. Either accept one of the existing answers or write a new answer yourself and accept that (to remove the question from the "unsolved" queue)

Answer (score 0):

Use `choice` command

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-3*delims=: " %%i in ('netsh wlan show networks ^| findstr "SSID"') do (
    set "count=!count!%%j"
    set "SSID%%j=%%k
    echo %%j: %%k
)
choice /c %count% /m "Choose an SSID:"
set "SSID=!SSID%errorlevel%!"
echo your SSID is: %SSID%
```

The above code will replace the following lines:

```
netsh wlan show networks | findstr SSID
echo.
@echo  Please type in your current connected WiFi name 
set /p  SSID="SSID: "
echo your SSID is: %SSID%
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much for your help.  If I could buy you a beer, I would

Comment: Thank you so much, guys.  Although I used both, have gone with the following

Answer (score 0):

Here is to get to which network you are connected:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal 
set "current=no network"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('netsh wlan show all ^| find " SSID  "') do set "current=%%a"
echo your are currently connected to %current%.
```

Comment: That works an absolute treat, thank you. I have changed it a little bit to the following :