# How to display the name of the network to which it is connected using cmd/bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to display the name of the network you are connected to in cmd, I tried to create a script

> ```
> netsh wlan show interfaces | findstr /C:"SSID:"
> ```

But when I run the script it shows this result

> ```
> SSID: networkname
> ```

I want a way to display only the network name without spaces and without displaying the word `SSID` and `:`

Comment: FYI, whilst the two may often match, the Name of the interface is not its SSID. Please clarify whether you want the interface Name or the SSID.

Comment: I want the network name, when you type cmd (netsh wlan show interfaces) the network name appears in the SSID field

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660008/input-from-users-for-batch-script)

Comment: @Hack1, the Name appears in the `Profile` line, the SSID appears in the `SSID` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer an alternative using WMI:

Getting help from [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic):

```sh
@For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 /NameSpace:\\Root\StandardCimv2 Path MSFT_NetConnectionProfile Where
 "IPv4Connectivity='4' And Name Is Not Null" Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL'
) Do @Echo %%G
```

Getting help from [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript):

```sh
<!-- ::Script Language="Batch"
@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"')Do @Echo(%%G
@Pause&Exit /B
--><Job><Script Language="VBScript">
        Set objWMI = GetObject("WINMGMTS:\\.\ROOT\StandardCimv2")
        WQL = "Select * From MSFT_NetConnectionProfile" +_
         " Where IPv4Connectivity='4' And Name Is Not Null"
        Set Instances = objWMI.ExecQuery(WQL)
        For Each Instance In Instances 
            Wscript.Echo Instance.Name
        Next</Script></Job>
```

---

Should you have wanted the `SSID` using your initial command you should be aware that the output from NetSh is in tabular format and could include or exclude space characters. I might therefore offer this type of methodology:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SSID=" & For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show Interfaces 2^>NUL ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^[ ][ ]*SSID[ ][ ]*:[ ][ ]*[^ ][^ ]*"'
) Do (Set "SSID=%%H" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ("!SSID:~1!") Do EndLocal & Set "SSID=%%I")
If Defined SSID (Echo "%SSID%"
    Pause)
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

Using that same methodology, you could also isolate the `Profile` name instead:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Profile=" & For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show Interfaces 2^>NUL ^|
 %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R
 /C:"^[ ][ ]*Profile[ ][ ]*:[ ][ ]*[^ ][^ ]*"') Do (Set "Profile=%%H"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In (
        "!Profile:~1!") Do EndLocal & Set "Profile=%%I")
If Defined Profile (Echo "%Profile%"
    Pause)
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

You may notice, as my experience very often has, that your result includes a trailing space, which could potentially prove problematic. For that reason, I'd advise that you do not rely upon the tabular output from NetSh.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for /f`:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims= " %%N in (`netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr /C:"SSID:") do (
  set nw_name=%%N
  echo Found a network: !nw_name!
)
```

This `for` will split the result of the filtered `netsh` command (`usebackq`) on spaces (`delims`), will take the 2nd token (`tokens`), then you'll find it in loop variable `%%N`. Take care to put it in another variable, because `%%N` do not exist anymore once loop is finished.

See also `for /?` on command prompt for details.

Comment: I think the script has several errors

Comment: Tell me where... Did you tested it? Which errors are displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to see you already have an answer. Here is another way to do it that will run in a `batch-file` run by `cmd`.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-NetConnectionProfile | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq 'Wi-Fi').Name"') DO (SET "nw_name=%%~A")
ECHO %nw_name%
```